# How is the 8th greek mode Hypomixolydian illustrated harmonically?

Tags: modes

I'm digging into musical modes and came across this article on how the greek mode were used therapeutically. http://wisdomofhypatia.com/OM/BA/MT.html#Performance
He illustrates many facets of each mode, of which there are 8 instead of 7 by most accounts and certainly in traditional western music,but does not give any notes or actual notation of how the 8th mode (Hypomixolydian).
The modes are in pairs:
Dorian
Hypodorian
Phrygian
Hypophrygian
Lydian
Hypolydian
Mixolydian
Hypomixolydian

If related to the traditional 7 modes:
Ionian
Dorian
Phrygian
Lydian
Mixolydian
Aeolian
Locrian

What would be the notes used in Hypomixolydian?

Comment: The website conflates ideas from Ancient Greek music theory with those of the medieval church system and gets both wrong, including citing sources (e.g., Baker) that have nothing to do with the esoteric subject at hand and which the author clearly misunderstands, at best. Even within the world of pseudo-science the site is of no use and should be disregarded.

Comment: What is true: ancient Greeks did believe that specific modes could influence the hearers and induce specific psychological and somatic responses (though they didn't all agree on the details). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_system_of_ancient_Greece#Ethos and other sources.

Answer (score 1):

The page you link to contains a good deal of misinformation.  Hypomixolydian was not a Greek mode; it was a feature of the medieval church mode system.

The eight modes of that system correspond to four of the modern modes.  Dorian and Hypodorian correspond more or less to modern Dorian mode because they both had D as the final note; they differed by virtue of their range and by the identity of the "dominant" note, also known as the "tenor."

Similarly, the other three modes and their "hypo-" partners correspond to the like-named modes of the modern modal system.  The "plain" modes are known as the authentic modes.  The "hypo-" modes are known as their "plagal" counterparts.

The three other modes, Ionian, Aeolian, and Locrian, were not part of the traditional system.  The first two were invented in the 16th century and the last in the 18th (it was never really in use; it was only identified as a theoretical abstraction through a process of generalization).

The seven Greek modes were generally not the same as their medieval namesakes.  The discussion at https://www.britannica.com/art/mode-music is a decent introduction.  It include this chart:

```
A G FE D CB A   Hypodorian  
G FE D CB A G   Hypophrygian    
FE D CB A G F   Hypolydian  
E D CB A G FE   Dorian  
D CB A G FE D   Phrygian    
CB A G FE D C   Lydian  
B A G FE D CB   Mixolydian
```

There is no Hypomixolydian mode.